# Sums with von-Mangoldt function $\Lambda$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Let $\Lambda$ be the  [von-Mangoldt function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function).
What is the estimate for the sum  is

$$\sum_{\substack{1\leq x\leq n\\1\leq y\leq n}}\Lambda(x)\Lambda(y)=\psi(n)\psi(n)\sim n^2.$$
$\psi$ is the Chebyshev function.

But in twin prime conjecture for a fixed integer $a$,
$$\sum_{x\leq a} \Lambda(x)\Lambda(x+a)\sim C n$$ Here $C$ is the twin prime constant. I'm not able to distinguish the difference between two sums.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Write out the first sum for, say, $n=3$, and the second for, say, $a=3$, and see how different they are.

Comment: Ohh! Thank you !